# Error while receiving data into ListView on android via JSON parser

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-asynctask, android-json

I am getting an error while trying to get data from a database via JSON request. I am using an arrayList-Hashmap. I am getting a JSON error. 
Here is my logcat. Please help

`03-20 04:59:18.245: E/JSON Parser(2438): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): Process: com.example.shareity, PID: 2438
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.example.shareity.ListTest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ListTest.java:134)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at com.example.shareity.ListTest$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(ListTest.java:1)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-20 04:59:20.716: E/AndroidRuntime(2438):     ... 4 more
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.shareity.ListTest has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{322444a1 V.E..... R......D 0,0-480,174} that was originally added here
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at com.example.shareity.ListTest$LoadAllProducts.onPreExecute(ListTest.java:121)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at com.example.shareity.ListTest.onCreate(ListTest.java:61)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
03-20 04:59:29.035: E/WindowManager(2438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)`

Here is my JSON Parser code.

```
`public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        //from here
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!line.startsWith("<", 0)){
                if(!line.startsWith("(", 0)){
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}`
```

And this is the main activity code

```
package com.example.shareity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import com.example.shareity.library.JSONParser;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListTest extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/shareity/get_all.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "eid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "ename";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_events);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ListTest.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ListTest.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ListTest.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ListTest.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Would you mind sharing the code snippets also along with this error stack.

Comment: Please read error carefully error came due to you trying to convert string to JSONObject.

Comment: ListTest.java:134;
java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString();
type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I see the error. I don't know how to rectify it. I am very new to android. Please help me @HareshChhelana

Comment: @Daenarys I have added the code. Please help